# Adding Python 2.7 to an app packet after macOS 12.3 does no longer include Python

Tags: macos, python-2.7, crossover

Last year I got a *PortJump* packet from Codeweavers for an [open source Windows software](https://www.easyct.de), not knowing that it uses Python 2.7  supplied by macOS < 12.3 only (Python 2.7 was marked deprecated by 2020 and Apple even announced that it wouldn't be included in the future anymore back in 2019.)

```
Termination Reason: Namespace DYLD, Code 1 Library missing. Library not loaded: /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Pyt
Referenced from: /Applications/EasyCash&Tax.app/Contents/MacOS/EasyCash&Tax
Reason: tried: '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Python' (no such file)
(terminated at launch; ignore backtrace)
```

This means that every user updating to 12.3 won't be able to start the software any longer. What is the best approach to make the software run again on macOS (other than to pay Codeweavers some thousands of $$ again, just to move from the underlying Crossover 20 to 21 -- given that Codeweavers have replaced the Python 2.7 reference already in 21)?

To be more precise, any of these questions answered would help me:

1. Is there a chance to quickly replace the missing Python interpreter on OS level so the built-in Crossover would work again?
2. What steps need to be taken to include a Python 2.7 in the app packet, e.g. where is it referenced?
3. Is there an easy way to move to Python 3?
4. As I understand, Python is just used for the Crossover GUI, which isn't needed by my software. Maybe the Python reference can be removed alltogether?

(I'm not a Mac-native, so bear with me, if I'm missing the point.)

Comment: Hi did you make any progress on this ?

Comment: @kofifus I asked Codeweavers to apply a patch set to the package (which seems to be not as trivial as one would think).

Comment: thanks! did they patch it for free ?

Comment: @kofifus No, but because it's free software, they agreed to a discount. Do you also have a PortJump package?

Comment: Hmmm not sure, I'll contact them thanks !

Comment: @kofifus I got the new package and will write an answer after I have analysed the patch.

Answer (score 1):

Got a patch from Codeweavers but the [the difference](https://github.com/Thomas-Mielke-Software/EasyCashMacRohpaket/commit/c3227c50ed53f590a021476d9d1ec0a6cc97107a) is hard to spot as they just updated the Crossover version from 20.0 to 20.4, including a completely new wine version.

But I stumbled upon [a note in the credits file](https://github.com/Thomas-Mielke-Software/EasyCashMacRohpaket/blob/c3227c50ed53f590a021476d9d1ec0a6cc97107a/EasyCash%26Tax.app/Contents/Resources/English.lproj/Credits.html#L25) about "the site module from python.org, modified to ignore /Library/Python". There seems to be an issue with python paths in MacOS as mentioned [here](https://liam.page/en/2022/04/01/fix-missing-Python2-7-on-macOS-Monterey-12-3/) btw.

Even if this answer may be not fully satisfying, maybe it helps someone. If you discover further details, please leave a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Installing python 2.7.18 resolved this issue for me.
Download it from the official site https://www.python.org/ftp/python/2.7.18/python-2.7.18-macosx10.9.pkg